# Issues opening everything

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management, skype, dependencies

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04. I had issues opening Skype. I looked at a few tutorials that I found from Google searches to no avail.

I figured it may just be an issue and went to try and update through "Update Manager" and got this error:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
'E:Malformed line 7 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)'
```

Anything I try to open for the most part involving Skype, minecraft, Imvu, etc. just comes up saying there is a "System Error", and that I should report it.

I also tried updating just the Ubuntu Software Center and got this, also get this for Skype:

```
jesusllama@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
[sudo] password for jesusllama: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of software-center is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.23) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-dbus:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-network:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-xml:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After trying what someone told me to do after changing whats in my sources.list file I updated... This is what I got:

jesusllama@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for jesusllama: 
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [254 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [609 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [4,627 B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [72.2 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2,182 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [267 kB] 
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4,620 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [74.3 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [10.1 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [200 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,368 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [74 B]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [71 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.6 kB]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [122 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [621 kB]
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en [995 B]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en [1,253 B]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en [45.6 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [10.0 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [203 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.8 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [3,564 B]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex [2,605 B]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex [2,461 B]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [2,850 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en [273 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7,834 B]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,432 B]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [117 kB]
Fetched 3,044 kB in 5s (517 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
jesusllama@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386:
 skype:i386 depends on libasound2 (>= 1.0.23).
 skype:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~).
 skype:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.7).
 skype:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 skype:i386 depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3).
 skype:i386 depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype:i386 depends on libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3).
 skype:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1).
 skype:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype:i386 depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36).
 skype:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6).
 skype:i386 depends on libx11-6.
 skype:i386 depends on libxext6.
 skype:i386 depends on libxss1.
 skype:i386 depends on libxv1.
 skype:i386 depends on libssl1.0.0.
dpkg: error processing skype:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype:i386
jesusllama@ubuntu:~$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the contents of the file /etc/apt/sources.list

This error should be resolved first, as it may impact your installation.
'E:Malformed line 7 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)'

Added the following based on seeing sources.list:

Could you try the following:

Open a terminal window (under Accessories->Terminal Emulator  in your menu) and type the following (first sudo command will prompt for password, enter your password when prompted):

```
name@server:~$ cd /etc/apt
name@server:/etc/apt$ sudo cp sources.list sources.list.bak
name@server:/etc/apt$ sudo gedit sources.list
```

replace the contents of your sources.list file with :

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse

Then save the file.

Back in your terminal type:

```
name@server:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
name@server:sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: How exactly do I look at the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: using a text editor, e.g. gedit, then open the file and copy past the contents here.

Comment: # /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

Comment: deb http:archive.canonical.com/ partner
deb-src http:archive.canonical.com/ partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

Comment: Some of these entries look incorrect in format : would have suspected they should look something like: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise.....

Comment: As stated above I just installed Ubuntu, i'm not familiar with any sort of Linux and I heart Ubuntu was a good place to start.

I haven't changed anything as I can't, and anything I try to change I just get errors.

Maybe if I re-install? Or maybe theres an easy way to reformat it and maybe that will help?

Comment: Edited the Original post with the error I got after trying dpkg --configure -a

Comment: Seems the commenting system here is truncating the <http://> piece from lines quoted.  However the two partner entries "deb http:archive.canonical.com/ partner <br> deb-src http:archive.canonical.com/ partner" definitely look wrong. You should at a minimum replace the "http:archive" piece with <http://archive...>

Comment: Try first of all removing the half installed skype  from terminal window type:   "sudo apt-get remove skype"   then try the instructions in this post for installing skype from the terminal window:   http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-skype-in-ubuntu-12-04precise.html

Comment: After it telling me a LOT of lines having to do with unpackaging and selecting / deselecting packages it ended with this: ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
The following package disappeared from your system as
all files have been overwritten by other packages:
  skype
Note: This is done automatic and on purpose by dpkg.

Comment: Also, my update manager just popped up and started downloading 202 updates and 315.9 MB will be downloaded

Comment: That is a good thing, the haf installed skype is removed and it means that your sources list is now correct and updates are being applied. When this updating is finished try following the link above to install skype

Comment: Afterward couldn't I just use the Ubuntu software Center and download the skype Application from there so I don't mess anything up?

Comment: Yes absolutely, if it is in there. I no longer have a 12.04 system to hand, so not sure if skype is in the main repos or if you need to add a partner repo. Just be careful as it looks like the partner repo entry that got added last time may have caused your original problem.

Comment: Sounds good, I hope Ubuntu / Linux in general is as fun as people say once you get the majority of it down. Thanks a ton for helping me. I hope to eventually understand Linux as a whole.

Comment: No worries, generally people will be helpful. If this has helped, mark my answer as accepted.